# What can't I use my model's DateTimeField in my view method?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

In a Django app, I'm trying to display my model's information on a page, but when trying to display the creation date, using a `DateTimeField`, it returns a server error. Here is my code:

**Model**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**View**

```
def user_detail(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)

    # Debugging
    print user.name # Works fine, prints "ZAD-Man"
    print user.created_date # Works fine, prints "2014-07-21 00:00:00"
    print type(user.created_date) # Breaks with a 500 Server Error

    html = "<dt>Name</dt><dd>" + user.name + "</dd><dt>Date Added</dt><dd>" + user.created_date + "</dd>" # Breaks (when the debug lines are removed so that it reaches here)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Everything works fine until I try to use `created_date`, whether in `type()` or adding it to a string. What am I doing wrong, and how should I fix it?

EDIT: Here are the specific errors:

When it breaks on `type(user.created_date)`, I get:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

When it breaks on `...+ user.created_date +...` (which happens if I remove the debug lines) I get:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found
```

Comment: what do you mean by `breaks` ? What is the error you see ?

Comment: It's a 500 Server Error in the Django log and Chrome's console.

Comment: In the network tab, When you click on the entry with the error, you can see the error.

Comment: AH! Very useful. I'll edit the question with that info.

Comment: So that is the issue - as the answers provided, just cast it to string explicitly. Or else you are doing `str + datetime + str` which is causing the issue. Just FYI - The error is not actually where you think it is. It in the `html = ..` line

Comment: Well, it does break on the `print type(user.created_date)` line whenever I include that debug code, because when it's included it doesn't make it past that line, throwing the first `TypeError` I included above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of concerns is what is one of the things [Django philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/) is about. HTML code you have in the view should extracted into the template and rendered in the view with passing the `user` object in the context:

`mytemplate.html`:

```
<dt>Name</dt>
<dd>{{ user.name }}</dd>
<dt>Date Added</dt>
<dd>{{ user.created_date }}</dd>
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def user_detail(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'user': user})
```

Also, instead of functional-based-views, consider switching to  [Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/). To be specific, the view you have resembles [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep it this way since it's being used by an AJAX call to swap out HTML. Otherwise I would definitely make it more along these lines.

Comment: @ZAD-Man you can still have a template and render it.

Comment: Oh...I think I understand. When I say `return render(request, "foo.html")`, it's just returning HTML, which I could give to my AJAX, just like I do here? Is that right?

Comment: Thank you, that realization will do tons for me going forward. :)

Answer (score 2):

can you try doing

```
html = "<dt>Name</dt><dd> {}  </dd><dt>Date Added</dt><dd> {} </dd>".format(user.name, user.created_date)
```

you can also call str() on the datetime value, and keep the html element + format.

EDIT

I am not sure exactly why type isnt working for you. Can you post the code of how the time gets saved to the model? I did a test run of a django model with a field set as so:

```
date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I tested your problem out in the shell

```
>>> print t.date 
2014-06-23 
>>> print type(t.date) 
<type 'datetime.date'> 
>>> print type(t.time) 
<type 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: Both ways works for me, thanks. I'm going to hold off on accepting until I see something with a little more explanation (especially why `type()` didn't work for it), but thank you for helping me to move on in the problem. :)

Comment: I added some more explanation to my post.

Comment: I use a simple `CreateView` to add it. I only entered the date, so it defaulted to 00:00:00 for the time.